# Right-to-left reversed text and alignment issue in mobaxterm on Linux

Tags: linux, wine

I have install Wine-1.8.0 on Ubuntu 16.04. The issue is that the text in mobaxterm is displayed right-to-left (reversed), aligned to the right, which the screenshot below shows.

Other .exe files working fine using Wine.

[image]

Error Message :

```
fixme: class: CLASS_GetClassLong offset -12 (GCLP_HCURSOR) not supported on other process windown 0x104a6
```

Anyone have idea why this error occur or any other alternative solution to fix it ?

Comment: I think you have to tell us a bit more. I don't know what it's supposed to look like, so I don't see what the issue is.

Comment: Psst!  Kusalananda!  Where it says `bat time ot <nruter> sserP` on the right in the screenshot, the screen should be reading `Press <return> to emit tab` on the left.  And so on.

Comment: @Kusalananda here alignment issue; It should be Left to right.

Comment: @JdeBP _Ha ha! That's too funny!_ I couldn't make out what the characters were in the screenshot (too small), so I assumed it was Hebrew. It never occurred to me that "RTL alignment" meant "flipped horizontally".

Comment: My guess is that mobaxterm uses some infrequently used combination of parameters for drawing routines that are not emulated correctly in Wine. File a bug on Winehq.

Comment: So he did: https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42139

Comment: @Yaron This bug generated by me

Comment: @RaviG. that's exactly what I said.

Comment: @Yaron check my case https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42139 and did you try any another alternative of wine ?

Comment: @RaviG. Nope, what is your locale? (type locale in your terminal)

Comment: @Yaron it's showing revers if i write "localte", Are you troubleshoot this issue or any solution for this?

Comment: @Ravi I meant before the command used to run mobaxterm, not inside mobaxterm, the command should probably start with `wine…`.

Comment: Any solution ? I have same problem.